# Login instance in the setup method of selenium

Tags: python, django, selenium-webdriver

I'm currently testing the website I'm developing using Selenium.  The only thing that I cant figure out is how to create a login instance so that my test classes do not have to compound on each other.

Further explanation:

```
class CreateListingTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/")
        *** create login instance here ***

    def test_createListing(self):
        driver = self.driver
        *** continue with test method ***
```

Most of the classes I'm trying to test require that a user needs to be logged in so the test can complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each instance of Selenium is independent and starts with a clean history and no cookie. You could simply implement a login page object:

```
class CreateListingTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        PageLogin(self.driver) \
          .visit() \
          .login(name, password)

    def test_createListing(self):
        driver = self.driver
        *** continue with test method ***

class PageLogin(object):

    url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/"

    def __init__(self, driver):
      self.driver = driver

    def visit(self):
        self.driver.get(self.url)
        ...
        return self

    def login(self, name, password):
        ...
        return self

    def logout(self):
        ...
        return self
```

Comment: Thank you so much!